# mongodb group and combine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a doc that has a schema like `{'year-month-day','others'}` and I want to convert `'year-month-day` to an ISODate time so I can use `$match:{'$gte:targetDate'}`

I have several problems:

1. I am using pymongo, which dones support javaciprt, so I can not use `new Date()` in python and at the same time `datetime` is not working as well because it can not read `'$year'`.

I think one way to achieve the above goal is first get the substrings of `'year-month-day'` and after aggregation I can use `forEach(function(x){...})` to create a `ISODate` for each date and compare with `target` but doing means I will have to scan through every docs in the database which I dont think is a good choice.

2. If the first is not doable in pymongo, how can I do it by mongodb query? how can I use project to create a column with new data type?(like what I did in the second project).
3. Is there any way to do javascrip inside pymongo?

My script is like following:

```
Collection.aggregate([                    
                {
                    '$project':{
                        'year':{'$substr':['$year-month-day',0,4]},
                        'month':{'$substr':['$year-month-day',5,2]},
                        'day':{'$substr':['$year-month-day',8,2]},
                        'others':'others'
                     }    
                },
                {
                    '$project':{
                        'approTime':new Date(Date.UTC('$year','$month','$day')),
                        'others':'others'
                     }    
                },
                {
                    '$group':{
                        '_id':{
                            'approTime':'$approTime',
                            'others':'others'
                        },
                        'count':{'$sum':1}
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You cannot "cast" to other values in the aggregation pipeline or "inject" functions in code from outside. You cannot even do what you are asking in JavaScript so it has nothing to do with pymongo. Just group on your existing fields and process to a date object while parsing the results

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the field `'year-month-day'` to mongoDB native ISODate data type by using the **[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)** module which is stored under the hood as the native date object in MongoDB:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime

client = MongoClient('host', port)
db = client['database']
col = db['collection']
attr = 'year-month-day'
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f" #date_format is the format of the string eg : "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
for doc in col.find():
    if doc[attr]:
        if type(doc[attr]) is not datetime:
            isodate = datetime.strptime(doc[attr], date_format)
            col.update({'_id': doc['_id']}, {'$set': {attr: isodate}})
```

This can also be done in Mongo shell as:

```
db.collection.find({
    "$and": [
        { "year-month-day": { "$exists": true } },
        { "year-month-day": { "$not": {"$type": 9} } }
    ]
}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    doc["year-month-day"] = new Date(doc["year-month-day"]);
    db.collection.save(doc); 
})
```

Comment: thanks you the answer, I know I can do this. but it will read all most all the docs in the collection to find out which date is thte one I want. So I want to use `{$gte:{}}` to filter out the date more quickly by one query. Also, I not sure if the `gte` will have the save cost as forEach but I guess `gte` will be faster since all the operation will be on the database side instead of local